# How do you say that you have/do not have a body part

Tags: phrase-requests

For example, someone who was born without an arm, or has an extra leg and wants to be able to express this in words. Or perhaps in a fantasy setting have retractable wings, and wants to tell people this.

"I have wings"
"I have an extra arm"
"I only have nine fingers" etc.

Comment: Which do you want, a generic term (single word) for "deformity/anomaly", or a sentence pattern "I (do not) have X in/on my Y"?

Comment: more of a sentence pattern. Like is it 「翼がある」, 「足がない」etc or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> （何に）手・足・胃・頭・鼻　がある。 (X has) a hand/leg/stomach/head/nose.

should be sufficient.

If you need to quantify, you could say

> 狼男には耳が２つある。 A werewolf has two ears.

Comment: Ok so it was ある after all, but I see, you have to use に after the being in question. So if i were to say 'I have wings on my back' it would be: '私の背中には翼がある, right?

Comment: Yes you could say that. に is commonly a location marker, after all.